# Show center tick value radar chart- Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I have a radar chart and I'd like to display the value for the tick at the center of the chart over the center. My `r` scale is set up as follows, and my data is an integer ranging from 1-5.

```js
    scales: {
      r: {
        min: 1,
        max: 5,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 1,
          z: 10,
        },
      },
    },
```

Over the center of the radar chart, I'd like the tick value displayed, like it's displayed for all other values. Setting my `min` to 0 (one step size lower than my actual min) displays my ticks, but I'd like the center of my graph to be labeled instead of having a minimum size between the center and the first tick.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a custom plugin to draw it on the canvas yourself like so:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      centerTick: {
        //color: 'grey' // Set custom color for y
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [{
    id: 'centerTick',
    afterDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
      const {
        ctx
      } = chart;
      ctx.fillStyle = opts.color || Chart.defaults.color;
      ctx.fillText(chart.scales.r.min, chart.scales.r.xCenter - (ctx.measureText(chart.scales.r.min).width / 2), chart.scales.r.yCenter)
    }
  }]
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```